# Почему сторонние домены переадресовывают на мой сайт?

Tags: ddos

На днях случилась DDoS атака на мой сайт, в совокупности сервер (на один IP). Подсоединил новый IP, все сайты заработали. Но после этого на один из моих сайтов начала наблюдаться чрезмерная активность, около 100 доменов по метрике переадресовывают на мой сайт. Может ли поисковик воспринять как дубли данные страницы и вообще, кому это выгодно? Как пресечь негативные последствия подобного?

Comment: Странно, что ещё никто не отозвался. Вы смотрели сайты, с которых идёт перенаправление? Что можете о них сказать? Каким образом происходит переадресация ([HTTP 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), [HTML <meta>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411567), [JS redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004))? В какой стране расположены IP-адреса? Простите за массу, вероятно, лишних вопросов, но ответы на них позволят лучше представить ситуацию.

Comment: @Андрей, я по вопросу подумал, что через dns - чужие домены ссылаются на его ip.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding

Comment: @Qwertiy, Вы правы, не принял во внимание, что после смены IP нагрузка снизилась.